# Construct vector of dates of the 1st and 15th of each month for axis breaks

Tags: r

I'm using R and want to construct a vector of dates, consisting of the 1st and 15th of each month, to use as breaks along the x-axis in a plot.

There are a lot of ways to do this but I'm trying to find the most elegant, straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution to this is to create a full vector of dates and then discard the ones I don't need by checking the day.

```
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
myDateBreaks = function(start, end, days=c(1, 15){
    dateBreaks = seq(as.Date(start), as.Date(end), by="1 day")
    dateBreaks %<>% .[day(dateBreaks) %in% days]
    return(dateBreaks)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by = "month")
rep(x, each = 2) + rep(c(0, 14), length(x))
 #[1] "2015-01-01" "2015-01-15" "2015-02-01" "2015-02-15" "2015-03-01" "2015-03-15" "2015-04-01" "2015-04-15" "2015-05-01" "2015-05-15" "2015-06-01" "2015-06-15"
#[13] "2015-07-01" "2015-07-15" "2015-08-01" "2015-08-15" "2015-09-01" "2015-09-15" "2015-10-01" "2015-10-15" "2015-11-01" "2015-11-15" "2015-12-01" "2015-12-15"
```